# Is the CBCL FACE DATABASE available?

Tags: faces

The CBCL FACE DATABASE includes 2,429 faces in the training set and is referenced on this page: http://cbcl.mit.edu/software-datasets/FaceData2.html

However, the download links for the faces.tar.gz - that I can find - yield "not found". For instance, http://cbcl.mit.edu/projects/cbcl/software-datasets/faces.tar.gz does not work. Neither does the link from http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/cbcl.old/software-datasets/FaceData2.html

Is this data available for download somewhere?

Comment: Note that there are many more face datasets, which you can find if you just Google [faces.tar.gz](https://www.google.nl/search?q=faces.tar.gz). I was doing this to find 'yours'...

Comment: I was look specifically for the CBCL Face Database. The linked faces.tar.gz seems to be another, - CMU Face Images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a copy of the dataset here:

http://www.ai.mit.edu/courses/6.899/lectures/faces.tar.gz

(27.5 MB zipped 110.3 MB unzipped)

Comment: cool! Finding lost datasets is one of my favorite things. I made an archive here at wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180208155206/http://www.ai.mit.edu/courses/6.899/lectures/faces.tar.gz